# Ruby on Rails 4.2 with Globalize gem for UUID table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, uuid, globalize

I use [Globalize gem](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) for my rails 4.2 project, and the table primary ID is UUID in postgre.

Here is the table migration codes and created translation table foreign key is integer type, not UUID.

```
class CreateMessageThreads < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up

    enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'

    create_table :message_threads, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.integer :resource_id, null: false
      t.string :resource_type, null: false
      t.datetime :deleted_at

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    MessageThread.create_translation_table!({
      :title => :string
    })

  end

  def down
    drop_table :message_threads
    MessageThread.drop_translation_table!
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make this UUID work??

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to use the hardcoded solution provided by Thomas Engelbrecht because not all my models use uuid.

Since the model is delegated we can check it's primary key type by adding a method :

```
def primary_key_type
    column_type(model.primary_key).to_sym
end
```

And i'm using Rails 4.2 so I can use the references **type** option ( [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16231) )

```
module Globalize
  module ActiveRecord
    module Migration
      class Migrator
        def primary_key_type
          column_type(model.primary_key).to_sym
        end

        def create_translation_table
          connection.create_table(translations_table_name, id: primary_key_type) do |t|
            t.references table_name.sub(/^#{table_name_prefix}/, '').singularize, null: false, type: primary_key_type
            t.string :locale, null: false
            t.timestamps null: false
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There must be a cleaner way, but I lack the experience to create a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and I solved it for rails 4.1.8 and globalize 4.0.2 by overwriting a globalize method and using the default method call in my migrations

```
Model.create_translation_table!({:name => :string}, {:migrate_data => true})
```

I created `/lib/globalize_uuid.rb`

```
  module Globalize
    module ActiveRecord
      module Migration
        class Migrator
          def create_translation_table
            connection.create_table(translations_table_name, id: :uuid) do |t|
              t.uuid table_name.sub(/^#{table_name_prefix}/, '').singularize + "_id", :null => false
              t.string :locale, :null => false
              t.timestamps
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

and changed my Rakefile to load the extension after load_tasks

```
Rails.application.load_tasks
require File.expand_path('../lib/globalize_uuid', __FILE__)
```

Not sure, if that solution survives a globalize3 update, but for now it works.